# Attempting to get executable path of process returns null

Tags: c#, process, null, executable-path

I have a piece of C# code that goes through all the running processes, finds a specific one, and gets its ExecutablePath. Problem is that, although it manages to find the wanted process, attempting to get the ExecutablePath returns null.

Now, I did some more experimenting on this, and it turns out that some processes the code gets a path for, others it returns null, and it appears to be arbitrary because I cannot find any correlation between the process and whether or not it returns the path.

The code is fine, but here it is anyways:

```
    string path = null;
    string processNameLowerCase = processName.ToLower() + ".exe";
    ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Process");
    ManagementObjectCollection managementObjects = managementClass.GetInstances();
    foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in managementObjects) {
        string managedProcessNameLowerCase = ((string)managementObject["Name"]).ToLower();
        if (managedProcessNameLowerCase.StartsWith(processNameLowerCase)) {
            path = (string)managementObject["ExecutablePath"];
            break;
        }
    }
```

All in all, what I want to know is how I can get the executable's path of the process I want.

Comment: I think that it isn't trouble of your code. It seems normal for certain processes to not to have ExecutablePath. Have you checked this processes with other tools?

Comment: What other tools are there that I can check the process with?

Comment: Process Explorer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Orsol, I've found out that the process itself doesn't really contain any info.